# t-sql get variable value from string with variable name

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way to convert `@my_variable` string into a value of `@my_variable`?

I have a table which stores names of variables. I need to get the value of this variable. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @second_variable AS NVARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @first_variable AS NVARCHAR(20);
SET @first_variable = '20';
SET @second_variable = SELECT '@first_variable'; --here I want that @second variable be assigned a value of "20".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely solution to your problem is to address/change/fix the design that requires why you would have a table that stores the names of variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_executesql` to execute strings (so you could do something like `sp_executesql 'SET @second_variable = ' + @name_of_variable;`). However, just putting that one statement into sp_executesql won't work, since [strings executed with `sp_executesql` or `EXECUTE` have their own variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx), and, therefore, neither @second_variable nor @first_variable are accessible.

So, what you could do would be to move your *complete* code (excluding the name of the variable) into a `sp_executesql` statement (untested):

```
DECLARE @name_of_variable NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @name_of_variable = ...

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'...lots of code... ' + @name_of_variable + ' ...lots of code...'
```

Answer (score 0):

try sp_executesql

```
declare @f nvarchar(20)
declare @s nvarchar(20)
declare @sT nvarchar(100)

set @f = '20'
set @sT = 'set @s = ''' + @f + ''''

exec sp_executesql @sT, N'@s nvarchar(20) output', @s output

print @s
```

Comment: I don't think this is what Markus wants: He wants to convert `'@f'` (note the quotes) to 20, with the string `'@f'` originating from a table. In your example, you use `@f` explicitly, i.e., it is bound at compile time.